# Using a variable in a regex pattern

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

I'm trying to write a function that will delete each line that matches a pattern. But that pattern will change based on the words held in a list (made from a dictionary). I was thinking it would be a simple `for` loop but the `for` loop variable doesn't expand inside the pattern.

```
for key in sort(keys(myDict))
    %g/^The key/d
endfor
```

But the loop looks for `^The key` instead of `^The red`, `^The green`, `^The blue`, etc. It doesn't expand the `key` variable to whatever it's holding.

How can I use a variable inside a regex pattern and have the variable expand? Or is there a better way entirely of achieving my goal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to "build" your global command using `:execute` like so:

```
for key in sort(keys(myDict))
    execute '%g/^The ' . key . '/d'
endfor
```

See `:h :exe` for more help using `:execute`.

Some thoughts:

- You may need to escaping your keys
- Might consider alternation. e.g. `\(red\|blue\|green\)`
- You may want to `:delete` into the black hole register to prevent any surprises. e.g. `:d_`

Comment: Perfect. This question doesn't require escaping inside of the variable but, just for completeness, how would one do that? Just use `split` on the variable and concatenate it back together into a new variable with escape characters where they are required?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use the `\V` or very non-magic along with the `escape()` function. e.g. `let regex = '\V\^The \(' . join(map(keys(myDict), 'escape(v:val, '''\''')'), '\|') . '\)'`